# Sharepoint Online: Cannot create Compound Index even when using Supported Column Types

Tags: sharepoint-online, compound-index

I'm trying to create a compound Index in Sharepoint Online for a list that currently has 26k items in it. The columns I wish to use (Type & Division) both have the following settings:

1. Setting

   1. Type = Choice
   2. Require that this column contains information = Yes
   3. Display choices using drop-down menu
   4. Do not allow "fill-in" choices
   5. Default Value = Choice, but nothing entered
   6. No column validation

The first column I wish to use (Type) does not have any nulls - I.e. all items have a value. When selecting this column as my primary column, the secondary column field becomes inaccessible (greyed out).

Admittedly, I do have an existing simple index using the same column (Type) - I haven;t yet treid deleting this index in that I'm already using this simple index in a number of other places. I've not read anything saying I cannot have one column participate in multiple indexes, so would prefer to leave the simple index as is.

[Sharepoint Supported Columns for Indexing](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-an-index-to-a-sharepoint-column-f3f00554-b7dc-44d1-a2ed-d477eac463b0#__supportedcolumns)